# How to get a list of areas out of a class bassed system

Tags: python-3.x

So I am in an intro to python class and we are just getting into class basses coding in python. I am looking to get a list of areas out of the plants in my list so that I can then take those areas, get a sum, and then subtract them from the area in the bed. I am having the trouble figuring out how to make a list of the area of the plants in my bed, which is only blueberries for now. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
class crop: 
    name  = "Crop" 
    sizeW = 0
    sizeL = 0
    areaOfCrop=sizeL * sizeW
    def print(self): 
        print("This is a ",self.name," and is ",self.sizeW,"X",self.sizeL, "and has an area of ",self.areaOfCrop) 
    def willItFit(self, W, L): 
        return self.sizeW <= W and self.sizeL <= L 
    def sameAs(self, crop): 
        return self.name == crop.name 

class plant(crop): 
    name  = "Plant" 
    sizeW = 1 
    sizeL = 1
    areaOfCrop = sizeL * sizeW

class parsley(plant): 
    name = "Parsley"

class shrub(crop): 
    name  = "Shrub" 
    sizeW = 2 
    sizeL = 2 
    areaOfCrop = sizeL * sizeW

class blueberries(shrub): 
    name = "Blueberries" 

class tree(crop): 
    name  = "tree" 
    sizeW = 3 
    sizeL = 3   
    areaOfCrop = sizeL * sizeW

class dwarfPeach(tree): 
    name = "Dwarf Peach" 

class bed: 
    sizeL = int(input("What is the length? "))
    sizeW = int(input("What is the width? "))
    crops = [blueberries()] # The list of crops in this bed
    areaOfAllCrops = [crops[areaOfCrop()]] #this is where my problem is
    def print(self): 
        print("The bed is ", self.sizeL," x ", self.sizeW) 
        for c in self.crops: 
            c.print() 
    def maxSizeAvailable(self): 
         ''' area of bed-total area of all crops in be ''' 
         return (self.sizeW, self.sizeL)  
    def add(self, newCrop):    
        dimension = self.maxSizeAvailable() 
        if newCrop.willItFit(dimension[0], dimension[1]):
             self.crops.append(newCrop) 
    def remove(self, existingCrop): 
         for c in self.crops: 
             if c.sameAs(existingCrop): 
                self.crops.remove(c) 
    def checkFit(self, crop): 
         dimension = self.maxSizeAvailable()
         return crop.willItFit(dimension[0], dimension[1]) 
 b = bed()
 b.print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add up the areas of the `crop` instances in the `crops` list with `sum(x.areaOfCrop for x in crops)`. This is a generator expression that gets passed to the builtin function `sum`.

But I think you have a larger conceptual issue that will cause you problems later on even you get your immediate issue squared away. The issue is that you're exclusively using class attributes in your code, rather than instance attributes. While there are some situations where class attributes are useful, the overwhelming majority of the time you want to be dealing with instance attributes instead.

To create instance attributes, you need to make the assignments in a method, and assign to `self.attr` instead of just `attr`. Usually the place to initialize your instance attributes is the `__init__` method, which Python will call for you after it creates the new instance.

To give an example, your `crop` class should probably start with:

```
class crop:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.name  = "Crop" 
        self.sizeW = 0
        self.sizeL = 0
        self.areaOfCrop = sizeL * size
    # ...
```

Some of those values could be passed as arguments, rather than always getting set to the same constant. That leads me to a design question: Do you need all of your different plants to be instances of separate classes, or could they all be different instances of one class, with different data in their instance attributes attributes? (Don't be too concerned if you don't know the answer yet. It takes some experience with OOP to get good at designing classes.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this tip!ill give this a try latter and see if it works. I'm not sure if it would help or not. The professor gave us most of this code and told us to come up with this last part on our own. What you are suggesting is the bettet way, but  he is having us do this to learn the basics.